# netstat gives 1 as PID for all ssh connections

Tags: linux, ssh, pid, netstat

In my custom linux image using `netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15)` from the package `net-tools 1.60` I am seeing different behaviors for different linux versions..

On Linux 5.4.28:

```
# netstat -tnp | grep ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 <local_ip>:22          <client_ip>:14321       ESTABLISHED 29342/1
tcp        0     40 <local_ip>:22          <client_ip>:22470       ESTABLISHED 28443/0
```

On Linux 5.10.65:

```
#  netstat -tnp | grep ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0     52 <local_ip>:22          <client_ip>:22470       ESTABLISHED 1/init
tcp6       0     52 <local_ip>:22          <client_ip>:33679       ESTABLISHED 1/init
```

The thing to note here is that on Linux 5.10, netstat shows PID as `1` and process as `init` for all ssh sessions. But in older linux, I am seeing correct PIDs for all ssh sessions. I need to know the `client_ip` and the `PID` for every ssh session so I can kill the session for whichever client I want.

From online searches, I could not figure out any fixes.

One alternative that I can see till now is using `who` to get this output:

```
# who
root            pts/1           00:00   Jan 12 07:16:19  <client_ip>
root            pts/2           00:03   Jan 12 08:21:07  <client_ip>
```

`grep` this with `client_ip` then use `ps` and grep that with the second column, like `ps | grep pts/1` for first client.

Is there anything I can do to netstat to fix this though? Because netstat also give the client port which is useful for me.

Comment: "In my custom linux image"?  How about some details there?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about software development. You probably want to ask this on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note that depending on your system configuration, the results you are seeing are entirely valid: it is possible that your `init` process is listening on the port and starting up `sshd` instances in inetd-mode. See e.g. [this discussion](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=237077).

Comment: @AndrewHenle What details are needed though? I am using yocto to create a custom image using the "dunfell" branches from meta-openembed and poky... I am using net-tools 1.6 package as mentioned.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the link. I'll post the question on superuser/unix as well.